# How to insert the more than one data in the listbox to database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, insert, listbox

I have a register page. I want to insert the data on this page to the database. There is a listbox in this page. I want to let the user select one or more data in the listbox and insert it to the database correctly. For example a user selected basketball, football and volleyball in your favorite sports(listbox). Then my database should has basketball, football, volleyball in your favorite sports column. I hope I can tell. Because my english is not very good. Sorry.

This is the page: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G95dO.png

These codes are not working. What should I do?

My codes :

```
protected void btnKayitEt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Spordeneme;User ID=sa;Password=123456"))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("Insert into Kullanici (Ad,Soyad,Cinsiyet,Email,Sifre,SifreTekrar,Il,Ilce) Values (@ad,@soyad,@cinsiyet,@email,@sifre,@sifretekrar,@il,@ilce)",conn);
                    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ad",txtAdi.Text);
                    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@soyad",txtSoyAdi);
                    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cinsiyet", cnsyt.SelectedItem.Value);
                    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmaili.Text);
                    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sifre", txtSifresi.Text);
                    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sifretekrar", txtSifreTekrari.Text);
                    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@il", ddlil.SelectedItem.Value);
                    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ilce", ddlilce.SelectedItem.Value);
                    for (int i = 0; i < lbspor.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        komut.CommandText = "insert into Kullanici (FavoriSporlar) values (@favorispor)";
                        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@favorispor", lbspor.Items[i].ToString().Trim());
                        komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch
                {
                    lbl1.Text = "Hata Oluştu, kaydedilmedi";
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }`enter code here`
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add try{..}catch(Exception ex){...} and see the error message in "ex" variable. the main problem locates with the code inside the loop.

Comment: i did and error is "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'cinsiyet', table 'Spordeneme.dbo.Kullanici'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated." I can not enter a null value. what should i do now?

Comment: there are 2 solutions: the first solution is you should edit the column "cinsiyet" to allow NULL. the second solution is you must check   komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cinsiyet", cnsyt.SelectedItem.Value == Null ? String.Empty :  cnsyt.SelectedItem.Value)

Comment: i did first solution then the same error occurred in the other data. i never entered null value. i dont understand second solution sorry.